# find method doesn't work properly in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want my code to send specified username strings to `Profile` page within `username` props retrieved through `find()` method and put the result to a function called `user` as you can also clearly figure in the code below, but the thing is, find method doesn't really return only one case in my if-else statement in user function, for example, when I put `3`, which matches the first condition because of id number 3 already is in my dummy data, it must send the username to profile page matching the related username in my data list, however, it works in both conditions regardless of what I put in there, why doesn't it only one condition?

```
function App() {
  const data = [
    { id: 1, username: "jane", password: "1234" },
    { id: 2, username: "jack", password: "1234" },
    { id: 3, username: "john", password: "1234" },
    { id: 4, username: "elizabeth", password: "1234" },
  ];
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const user = (id) => {
    data.find((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        console.log(item.username);
        return item.username;
      } 
      else
      { console.log("user not found")}
    }
    );
  };

  setTimeout(() => {
    user(3);  // 3 is the id of the user and it will return the username after 3 seconds
    return;
  }, 3000);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Navbar</h1>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="login">Login</Link>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="users" element={<Profile />}>
          <Route path=":id" element={<Profile username={user} />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<h1>404 not found</h1>} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<h1>404 not found</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I really don't get this, I'm all stuck trying to fix this for hours and any help will be super appreciated, thanks a lot...

Comment: Nothing about this usage of the `find` method makes sense... (1) you're not doing anything with the *result* of `.find()`; (2) The callback passed to `.find()` doesn't always return anything at all, and never returns a boolean value; (3) You're setting `username={user}` in a component, but `user` is *a function*, which neither *is* a value nor *returns* a value.  It seems that "find doesn't work in React" is more accurately described as "how does find work in JavaScript".  From the usage in the code I'm afraid it's not clear to me at all what you're even trying to do.

Comment: `return item.username` [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) expects the return to be a truthy/falsy value. _"The callback must return a truthy value to indicate a matching element has been found"_. `user` should return `data.find`

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah you are right, got it all now thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) expects the callback to return `true` or `false` (to be precise a [*truthy* or *falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy?retiredLocale=de) value) and will return the **first** item which callback returns a *truthy* value or `undefined` if no callback returns a *truthy* value. You cannot decide what `find()` returns as it seems you want to.

You should use `find()` to get the user of interest and then use `user.username` to get the username.

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1, username: "jane", password: "1234" },
    { id: 2, username: "jack", password: "1234" },
    { id: 3, username: "john", password: "1234" },
    { id: 4, username: "elizabeth", password: "1234" },
  ];

const getUserById = (id) => data.find(user => user.id === id);
const userId = 3;
const user = getUserById(userId);
if(user !== undefined){
  console.log(`User with id ${userId} found.`)
  console.log(user);
  console.log(user.username);
} else console.log(`No user with id ${userId} found.`)
```

Comment: \*expects the callback to return a *truthy or falsy value*

Comment: Yes thanks, that's more precise. Added.

Comment: oh my goodness, how come i didnt figure it out! i was totally wrong expecting it to return username instead of either truthy/falsy values, many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The find() method returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.
Simply try, `let result = data.find(item => item.id === id)`